# Flutter: how to get magic numbers of file?

Tags: flutter, mime-types, content-type, filepicker, magic-numbers

I'm using [file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) to choose file from storage and sometimes it doesn't give an extension but I need to know an extension to send it to server side. I'm going to identify it by [Magic Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) like this

```
  print(lookupMimeType('test.html', headerBytes: [0xFF, 0xD8]));
  // image/jpeg
```

but don't know how to get it. Giving whole path to `lookupMimeType` doesn't help because [file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) caches file without extension. Can you help how to solve or how to figure it out ?

**P.S** Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 3):

To get the file header bytes you can do this:

```
List<int> fileBytes = File('PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE').readAsBytesSync().toList();

List<int> header = [];

fileBytes.forEach((element){
    if(element == 0) return;
    header.add(element);
});

print(lookupMimeType('test.html', headerBytes: header));
```